# Log4net highlightjs language grammar

Tags: javascript, log4net, vim-syntax-highlighting, regexp-grammars

How can I create and use a new syntax highlighter in **highlightjs** library?

I want to define such a grammar for log file in format of **log4net c#** library but I found no samples.

Any help is very welcomed, thanks.

Comment: Here is [a tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide) that discusses language grammar in the context of VS Code. It contains links to the most important concepts (e.g., TextMate grammars and  Oniguruma regular expressions) that hopefully will point you in the right direction.

Comment: @lsqhjs, It would be great if you can share what you have tried already. You must have browsed, went through some documentation, did some coding or whatever - Just say it here, which will help you to get better answers.